# Verify that a generated password contains necessary characters

Tags: vb.net, validation, visual-studio-2010, basic

Need a little help with an application I'm creating. Its just a simple password generator. I have the application generating the password with no issues but I need to add a step in that checks for: 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 number and 1 special character before displaying the password. If the password doesn't contain these values the password should then generate again.

I would like to keep the code I have, i just want to add a step in at the end.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is my code:

```
    Public Class Form1

    Dim AllCharacters As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789?!£$%^&*()_+[];'#,./?><~@:}{\|"
    Dim r As New Random
    Dim charIndex As Integer
    Dim finalpassword As String
    Dim passwordChars1() As Char = New Char(9) {}

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        For i As Integer = 0 To 9 - 1
            charIndex = r.Next(AllCharacters.Length)
            passwordChars1(i) = AllCharacters(charIndex)
        Next
        finalpassword = passwordChars1

        passwordbox.Text = finalpassword 'Displays Password on Main Form Window

    End Sub
```

Comment: You should read [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation)

Answer (score 0):

This is something you normally do when creating or changing a password.
I normally use something like the following function to validate the complexity of a password:

```
'PasswordComplexityRegex is a string value I get from a database at login, 
'if it is not present then a default one will be use.    
Dim PasswordComplexityRegex as String 
'MinimunPasswordLenght is also a number stored in a database if not present
'it will use a default, in this case 12.
Public Function validatePassword(ByVal pass As String) As Boolean
    Dim pattern As String = "[~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+';:,./<>?]"
    If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PasswordComplexityRegex)) Then
      pattern = PasswordComplexityRegex
    End If
    Dim patternRegex As Match = Regex.Match(pass, pattern)
    'In this case it checks that the length of the password is >= to 12
    If (IsDBNull(MinimunPasswordLenght) Or MinimunPasswordLenght = 0) Then
       MinimunPasswordLenght = 12
    End If
    Return (patternRegex.Success And pass.Length >= MinimunPasswordLenght)
End Function
```

It is key that you always test your Regex, it is a little bit more complex than some think.

Now use this Function to validate your password and determine is continuing or not. Something like:

```
If Not validatePassword(txtNewPassword.Text) Then
  MsgBox("Password need to be...", vbCritical, "Password not in compliance...")
End If
```

You should allow all characters including Unicode, and should not restrict the length more than strictly necessary, for example if MySQL limit it. You should encourage a combination of letters, numbers, caps, etc.

Nandostyle